# why checking for multiple conditions returns incorrect results

Tags: java, recursion

Given an array of ints, is it possible to divide the ints into two groups, so that the sum of one group is a multiple of 10, and the sum of the other group is odd. Every int must be in one group or the other. Write a recursive helper method that takes whatever arguments you like, and make the initial call to your recursive helper from splitOdd10(). (No loops needed.)

Here is my solution code: (and yes I used two helper methods instead of one )
And this is how I am trying to solve the problem: (please correct me if I am doing something wrong).

Each number in `nums` can end up in only one of the groups, `group1` or `group2`. For the case the element goes into group1 - `group1 += nums[start]` and recurse through in this way for every element in `nums` till the last item is passed-where the index `start` is out of bounds of `nums`- `start >= nums.length`. After doing this we end up with two groups `group1` and `group2` at the end of all the branches in this possibility 'tree'. Then check if there happens two groups such that the sum one group is a multiple of 10 and the sum other odd - `compare(group1, group2)`.

This is where, I think, my code is misbehaving - In the call to `compare(group1,group2)`. I try if `group1` is a multiple of 10 AND `group 2` is odd - `if( a%10 == 0  && b%2 == 1) return true;` and then, since we don't know the reverse happened and `group1` turned out to be odd AND `group2` a multiple of 10, I check for that too  `if( a%2 == 1 && b%10 == 0 ) return true;` This doesn't work for all cases.[Here is a screenshot of code output in codingbat.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYggn.png). But commenting out the first condition of `compare(group1,group2` magically fixes it.[Here is a working code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFA00.png)

```
public boolean splitOdd10(int[] nums) {
 return( splitter(nums,0,0,0) ); 
}
public boolean splitter(int [] nums,int start,  int group1, int group2){
  if (start >= nums.length ) return compare(group1,group2);

  if( splitter(nums,start + 1, group1 += nums[start], group2 ) ) return true; // first condition add element in group1 and recurse on 
  if( splitter(nums,start + 1, group1, group2  += nums[start] ) ) return true;// second condition add element to group2 

  return false;
}

public boolean compare( int a, int b){
  if( a%10 == 0  && b%2 == 1) return true;// <--- if I remove this line the code works
  if( a%2 == 1 && b%10 == 0 ) return true;
  return false;
}
```

my question is: how do we "know" which group to check for being odd and which to check for being a multiple of 10? I checked both groups for both conditions, but apparently that is wrong, and doesn't return correct result for some arrays. For example it returns 'true' for the array [10,0,5,5] instead of 'false'. Please help me understand why checking for both conditions is incorrect.

Comment: `+=` is a **modification operation**. That means the `group1 += nums[start]` you're calculating to pass into `splitter` in that first `if` *modifies* `group1`, and so you see the modified value in the second call to `splitter`. Is that intentional?

Comment: The first thing you need to do here is step through your code line-by-line with a debugger. Check that every aspect, every local variable, every return value etc is what you expect it to be.

Comment: I think it's not only a coding problem...

Comment: It is not necessarily possible to divide a collection of ints into two groups according to those rules. Here are examples: {1}, {1,2}, ..., {10, 12}, {12, 13}...

Comment: sorry about that, @T.J.Crowder, yes it is intentional. My line of thought is as such: for every 'element' of the array `nums` there are two possibilities: either it goes in to `group1` (hence the `group1 += nums[start]` or the other.

Comment: Are you sure that this isn't a lesson in implementing an Spliterator?

Comment: @je53y: The `group1 += nums[start]` happens **before** any conditional logic (other than `if (start >= nums.length )`), exactly as though it were before the second `if` (the one just after `if (start >= nums.length )`) -- and consequently that's where I'd put it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, algorithmically, this is easy.

Given a collection of ints, they may sum up to an odd or even number.

- If they sum up to an odd number, one possible splitting is to return all numbers into the sumIsOdd-bucket, while the sumMod10-bucket stays empty.
- If they sum up to a multiple of 10, which is a special case of an even sum, one valid solution is to sort all of them into the sumIsMod10-bucket, while the odd-bucket stays empty. But the odd bucket, as empty, doesn't sum up to an odd number, so this isn't a solution, but a fail.
- The third possibility is, that the sum is even, but not divisible by 10, then no matter how often we subtract 10 from the sum, (without even checking, if some of the numbers add up to such a sum), the sum of the rest will neither get odd, nor divisible by 10. Example: 36→26→16→6 - no rest will be odd, nor will it be divisible by 10.
- The last possibility is, that we subtract from an even sum, which is not by itself divisible by 10, a sum which is even, and put it into the odd-bucket. But the odd-bucket will then be even and a fail too, even if we reach a divisible-by-10 sum in the other bucket. Example: (100, 1) could be split into (1)(100), but (101)() is a solution too.

So the only, possible solution is a case, where the total sum is already odd, and putting all elements into the odd-bucket is a valid answer, since 0%10 is 0.

So you can either split it in the first step into an empty part on the one, and the whole thing on the other side, or it isn't splittable.

A more sophisticated question would be, to find two buckets with a minimum difference in the sum or the element count.

Comment: Thank you, you provided a way of solving the question in unbelievably simple way.